# How to run wkhtmltox

Tags: linux

I'm trying to setup a Docker container to have this tool installed.

https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

I downloaded the `.deb` file into my bare bones **focal** container using `ADD [url] .` and then ran the `/bin/sh` in the container interactively as the root user.

Once I can get it installed and running manually using shell commands, I can then figure out how to write a Dockerfile for it.

So far this is what's happened.

- I used `dpkg -i wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.focal_arm64.deb` to install it but it complained of a bunch of missing packages, the first of which was `fontconfig`.
- I used `apt-get install fontconfig` to install that, but this also complained of missing packages `The following packages have unmet dependencies:` and listed them for `fontconfig` but also weirdly listed them for `wkhtmltox` as well, as if it somehow knew or perhaps remembered the thing I tried to install.
- In the errors was a suggestion to run `apt --fix-broken install` which I did.
- Pages of stuff came up as it made changes and then it finished.
- I was then able to run `dpkg -i wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.focal_arm64.deb` again successfully.

And here's my problem: now it's installed, how do I run it? Trying executing `wkhtmltox` says `not found`.

I'm new to Linux, I don't really know what all of the above was really doing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the command line util is

```
wkhtmltopdf
```